# Javascript - Random images foreach user

Tags: javascript, php

I want to make a random images for each user who have no avatar. But the problem is random images just work for the first user.

I'm using gambar1.png for first default images, then when page refresh it will turn into a different and random images.

This is my view:

```
    <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>image/gambar1.png" class="img-thumbnail" id="defatar"/> user 1
    <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>image/gambar1.png" class="img-thumbnail" id="defatar"/> user 2
```

This is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var ErrorImages = new Array();
        ErrorImages[0] = "<?php echo base_url()?>image/gambar1.png";
        ErrorImages[1] = "<?php echo base_url()?>image/gambar2.png";
        ErrorImages[2] = "<?php echo base_url()?>image/gambar3.png";
        document.getElementById("defatar").src = ErrorImages[Math.floor(Math.random()*ErrorImages.length)];
    </script>
```

The random images work for user 1 but not work for user 2.

Any answer?

Comment: ID must be only one for page..

Comment: use loop. set id to 'defatar1','defatar2'... then in your selector something like 'document.getElementById("defatar" + loopindex)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ID` must be unique for page, you can't use one `ID` for several elements., instead `ID` you can use `class`, like this

PHP view,

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>image/gambar1.png" class="img-thumbnail defatar" /> user 1
<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>image/gambar1.png" class="img-thumbnail defatar" /> user 2
```

JS

```
var ErrorImages = [];

ErrorImages[0] = "image/gambar1.png";
ErrorImages[1] = "image/gambar2.png";
ErrorImages[2] = "image/gambar3.png";

var ErrorImagesLength = ErrorImages.length, 
    images = document.querySelectorAll('.defatar'),
    len    = images.length, 
    i;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  images[i].setAttribute('src', ErrorImages[Math.floor(Math.random()*ErrorImagesLength)]);
}
```

[`Example`](http://jsbin.com/susuma/1/edit?js,output)